# Linked list giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception

I am making a calculator that uses a linked list. It mostly works, but in one case it gives me an error. To declare a constant you use "=:"  =:constantname    to declare a variable you use "=" so =variablename

My error comes when the input is like this:

```
java P7.java -postfix
3
4
=:bob
8
=test
4
bob
```

when you type bob it gives:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cStack.getcon(P7.java:403)
    at P7.process(P7.java:208)
    at P7.main(P7.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:415)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

I am unsure how to fix this... Here is my code:

````java
import java.util.*;

public class P7 {
         static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         static int cnt = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) { 




        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No arguments!");
            usage();
        }

        else if (args[0].equals("--help")) {
                usage();

        }

        else if (args[0].equals("-postfix")) {

                //start the processor method 
                try {
                process();
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Did not recognize.");
            usage();
        }

    }
    public static void process() {
            Stack stack = new Stack();
            cStack cstack = new cStack();
        double temp = 0.0;      
        double val = 0.0;           //latest value
        double temp0 = 0.0;
        double temp1 = 0.0;
        double temp2 = 0.0;
        double temp3 = 0.0;
        double tempcon = 0.0;


        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {      //checks if double
                val = scan.nextDouble();
                stack.push(val);
                                    //pushes value on stack


            }

            else {
                String s = scan.next();

                if (s.equals("+")) {
                   stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());

                }
                else if (s.equals("-")) {
                    temp = stack.pop();
                    stack.push(stack.pop() - temp);

                }
                else if (s.equals("*")) {
                    stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop());

                }                
                else if (s.equals("~")) {
                        stack.push(stack.pop() * -1);

                }                    
                else if (s.equals("swap")) {
                        temp0 = stack.pop();
                        temp1 = stack.pop();
                        stack.push(temp0);
                        stack.push(temp1);
                }                   
                    else if (s.equals("copy")) {
                        temp2 = stack.pop();
                        stack.push(temp2);
                    stack.push(temp2);
                 }                
                else if (s.equals("/")) {
                    temp = stack.pop();
                    if (temp == 0.0) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Can't divide by zero. Exiting...");
                        System.exit(1);                 
                    }
                    else {  
                    stack.push(stack.pop() / temp);
                    }
                }

                else if (s.equals("'")) {
                        stack.push(1.0 / stack.pop());
                }

                else if (s.equals("**")) {
                        temp3 = stack.pop();
                        stack.push(Math.pow(stack.pop(), temp3));
                }

                else if (s.equals("peek")) {
                        System.out.println(stack.peek());

                }
                else if (s.equals("dump")) {
                        stack.dump();

                }

                else if (s.equals("=")) {

                    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Stack underflow, not enough values. Exiting.");
                        System.exit(0);

                    }

                    else {

                        System.out.println("Result = " + stack.pop() + ".");
                    System.out.println("There are " + stack.cnt() + " values remaining on the stack.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

                    /*else if (cstack.isValidCon(s)) {

                        String cName = s.substring(2);
                        if (cstack.constantExists(cName)) {
                            System.out.println("Constant name already exists.");
                        }
                        else {
                        tempcon = stack.pop();
                            cstack.setConstant(tempcon, cName, cstack.isValidCon(cName));
                            stack.push(tempcon);
                        }
                    }



                    else if (s.substring(0, 2).equals("=:") && !cstack.isValidCon(s)) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid constant name");
                    }
                    */


                else if (s.substring(0, 2).equals("=:") && (s.length() > 2)) {
                        String cName = s.substring(2);
                        if (!cstack.isValidCon(s)) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid constant name.");
                        }
                        else if (cstack.checkConName(cName) == true && cstack.isConOrVar(cName) == true) {                  
                                System.out.println("Constant name already in use.");

                            }
                            else {                          
                            cstack.setConstant(stack.peek(), cName, true);
                            }
                            }



                    else if (s.substring(0, 1).equals("=") && (s.length() > 1)) {
                        String vName = s.substring(1);
                        if (cstack.isValidVariable(s) == true) {

                            if (cstack.checkConName(vName) == true) {
                                System.out.println("Constant with name already exists.");
                            }
                            else {

                            cstack.setConstant(stack.peek(), vName, false);
                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            System.out.println("Didn't recognize input. Exiting.");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }





                else if (cstack.checkConName(s) == true) {
                        stack.push(cstack.getcon(s));

                }

                else if (cstack.checkVarName(s) == true) {
                        stack.push(cstack.getVar(s));
                }
                else if (cstack.checkVarName(s) == false || cstack.checkConName(s) == false) {
                    System.out.println("Didn't recognize input. Exiting.");
                    System.exit(0);
                }








                    else {
                    System.out.println("Didn't recognize input. Exiting.");
                    System.exit(1);                
                }



            }

        }

    }



    public static void usage() {
        System.out.println("Usage: P3");
        System.out.println("\"P3 --help\" to display this usage material.");
        System.out.println("\"\"P3 -postfix\" to accept input from standard input as a sequence");
        System.out.println("of numbers and operators. The numbers read are stored on a");
        System.out.println("stack until needed. When an operator is read, the required");
        System.out.println("operands are popped from the stack and used to perform the");
        System.out.println("calculation, with the result placed on the stack. Valid");
        System.out.println("operators are +, -, *, /, ~, ', *** swap, peek, dump, and copy which are performed as");
        System.out.println("addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, negation, swapping, and copying");
        System.out.println("respectively, and as described below. An additional");
        System.out.println("operator is =, which indicates that the value at the top of");
        System.out.println("the stack is popped from the stack and displayed along with");
        System.out.println("the number of values remaining on the stack.");
        System.out.println("Stack underflows generate an error message and halt the program.");
        System.out.println("Stack operations are performed as indicated");
        System.out.println("here.");
        System.out.println("+ : push(pop() + pop());");
        System.out.println("- : temp = pop(); push(pop() – temp;");
        System.out.println("* : push(pop() * pop());");
        System.out.println("/ : temp = pop(); push(pop() / temp;");
        System.out.println("= :");
        System.out.println("~ : Negation. Changes the sign of the top of the stack.");
        System.out.println("' : Inversion. push(1.0 / pop())");
        System.out.println("** : Exponentiation. temp = pop(); push(Math.pow(pop(), temp))");
        System.out.println("peek : display the current top-of-stack value.");
        System.out.println("dump : display the complete stack contents, one per line, starting with top-of-stack.");
        System.out.println("swap : temp0 = pop(); temp1 = pop(); push(temp0); push(temp1)");
        System.out.println("copy : temp = pop(); push(temp); push(temp);");


    }


}

class cNode {
    double cData;
    double vData;
    cNode cNext;
    String conName;
    String varName;
    boolean isConstant;
}

class cStack {
    private cNode cTop;

    public cStack() {
        this.cTop = null;
    }

    public boolean iscEmpty()
    {
        return cTop == null;
    }



    public void setConstant(double cval, String name, boolean isCon) {

        cNode cnode = new cNode();


        if (isCon == true) {
        cnode.isConstant = true;
        cnode.cData = cval;
        cnode.conName = name;
        }
        else {
            cnode.isConstant = false;
            cnode.vData = cval;
            cnode.varName = name;
        }
        cnode.cNext = cTop;
        cTop = cnode;


    }

    public boolean isConOrVar(String name) {
        boolean isACon = false;
        cNode temp2cNode = cTop;
        while (cTop != null) {
            if (name.equals(cTop.conName) && cTop.isConstant == true) {
                isACon = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (name.equals(cTop.conName) && cTop.isConstant == false) {
                isACon = false;
                cTop = cTop.cNext;
            }
            else {
                cTop = cTop.cNext;
            }
        }
        cTop = temp2cNode;
        return isACon;
    }

    public boolean checkConName(String a) {
        boolean found = false;
        String b;
        cNode temp1cNode = cTop;
        while (cTop != null) {
                if (a.equals(cTop.conName)) {
                        found = true;

                        break;
                }
                else {
                    cTop = (cTop).cNext;
        }

    }
    cTop = temp1cNode;
        return found;
    }

    public boolean checkVarName(String a) {
        boolean found1 = false;
        String b;
        cNode tempvNode = cTop;
        while (cTop != null) {
            if (a.equals(cTop.varName)) {
                found1 = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                cTop = cTop.cNext;
            }
        }
        cTop = tempvNode;
        return found1;
    }

    public boolean isValidVariable(String varName) {
        boolean isVar = false;
        int i;

        if ((varName.length() > 1) && varName.substring(0, 1).equals("=")) {

            for (i = 1; i < varName.length(); ++i) {
                char c = varName.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                    isVar = true;
                }
                else {
                    isVar = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isVar;
    }

    public double getcon(String name) {
        boolean found = false;
        cNode tempcNode = cTop;
        double retval = 0.0;

        while (cTop != null) {
            if (cTop.conName.compareTo(name) == 0) {
                 retval = cTop.cData;
                 found = true;
                 break;
            }

            else {
                cTop = (cTop).cNext;
            }
        }
        cTop = tempcNode;
        return retval;
    }

    public double getVar(String name) {
        boolean varFound = false;
        cNode tempVarNode = cTop;
        double retCon = 0.0;

        while (cTop != null) {
            if (cTop.varName.compareTo(name) == 0) {
                retCon = cTop.vData;
                varFound = true;
                break;

            }
            else {
                cTop = cTop.cNext;
            }
        }
        cTop = tempVarNode;
        return retCon;
    }


    public boolean constantExists(String name) {
        boolean exists = false;
        cNode tempNode = cTop;

        while (cTop != null && !exists) {
            if (cTop.conName.equals(name)) {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                cTop = (cTop).cNext;
            }

        }
        cTop = tempNode;
        return exists;


    }

    public boolean isValidCon(String conName) {
        boolean retbool = false;
        int i = 0;
        String check = conName.substring(2);
        if (conName.length() > 2) {
        if (conName.substring(0, 2).equals("=:") && conName.length() > 2 && conName.substring(2).length() >= 1) {

            for (i = 0; i < check.length(); ++i) {
                char c = check.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                    retbool = true;
                }
                else {
                    retbool = false;
            }
        }

        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
            return retbool;
            }



}


class Node
{
    double data;    
    Node next;      
};

class Stack
{
    private Node top;

    public Stack() {
        this.top = null;
    }

    public void dump() {
        Node tempNode = top;

        while (!isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(top.data);
            top = (top).next;
        }
        top = tempNode;
    }



    public void push(double x) 
    {

        Node node = new Node();

        if (node == null)
        {
            System.out.print("Overflow");
            return;
        }

        node.data = x;

        node.next = top;

        top = node;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return top == null;
    }

    public double peek()
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return top.data;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public double pop() 
    {
        // check for stack underflow
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Stack underflow");
        }
        if (top == null)
        {
            System.out.print("Stack Underflow");

        }


        double a = top.data;

        top = (top).next;
        return a;
    }

    public int cnt() {
        Node tempN = top;
        int cnt = 0;
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            ++cnt;
            top = (top).next;
        }
        top = tempN;
        return cnt;
    }
}


    ```
````